# What is the path rule of Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to build a basic static web server, very simple one, few lines, handle 3 requests, an icon, js, and html file:

Project struture:

```
-D：
  -project
    -build
      -index.html
      -fav.icon
      -dist.js
    -server.js
```

Code in server.js

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  //create dynamic filepath for response via requests MIME type
  let filePath = './build' + req.url;
  fs.access(filePath, callback(err){
    console.log(err);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': contentType});
    let file = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + filePath);
    file.pipe(res);
  });
});
```

Weird thing is that, the filePath worked last night as I recall, but I am not sure what happened or what I have changed, it is not working now. so I tried to debug it, now the console will show:

```
'no such file...D:\project.\build\'
```

there is a '.' there before '\build', so I tried to remove this:

```
let filePath = '/build' + req.url;
```

Then it will show

```
'no such file...D:\build\'
```

where is the 'project' directory? again, remove '/' brfore 'build':

```
let filePath = 'build' + req.url;
```

'project' comes back:

```
'no such file...D:\projectbuild\'
```

I tried to use path.resolve(__dirname, absolute path) and path.join(__dirname, relative path), they all return the same.

I do not know why I can visit my server last night, but not today, I recall that at somewhere I saw a link to 'Node file path rule' or 'Node file visit rule' something like that, I googled it and tried to search in Node Document, but no luck, so what is the rule of visiting a path in Node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so __dirname will be the directory your of the file you're running.  So for example if your current working directory is `D:\project` and you run `node server.js` then __dirname will return "D:\project" as you would expect.  However, if your current working directory is actually `D:\` and you run `node project\server.js` then you might not expect the result of "D:\project".

In the case of what you're doing, you want to join "__dirname" with "build" and then finally the filename in question.  If `req.url` is "index.html", you want to read the file located at `__dirname + \ + build + \ + index.html`.

So, the join function  you're looking for would be something like this:

```
var fileUrl = path.join(__dirname, 'build', req.url);
```

The `path.join` function should handle normalizing for the platform and so on.

Comment: thank you for the answer, it works, so for futher usage, can you please tell me what '/build' and './build' mean, I want to know more about Node file visiting path rules.

Comment: For that stuff, node just follows Unix path standards. So a path starting with a slash means "starting from the root directory". On Windows, /build would therefore mean D:\build, if you're in the D drive. Starting with a dot then a slash means "starting from the current directory". So if you're in D:\projects and you say ./build, the path would be D:\projects\build. You can play with it by going into a Node REPL and calling path.resolve() on whatever string path fragment you want to try out.